# C# Errors - Methods not found

Tags: c#

I have a message that keeps coming up as an error and the error persists and I do not know what method to implement so I can remove the error. I have tried in many ways with no luck.

```cs
namespace QueryNorthwindDB1
{
    partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void lbl_ID_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            lbl_ID.Text = "235489";
        }

        private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            lb_FName.Text = "Liliana";
        }

        private void lb_LName_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            lb_LName.Text = "Patrascanu";
        }

        private void lb_BDate_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            lb_BDate.Text = "6 March 1995";
        }

        private void btDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            using (var ctx = new QueryNorthwindDB1.NorthwindEntities())
            {
                var Employee = (from Employees in ctx.Employees where e.EmployeeID == 15 select e).First();
                ctx.Employees.Remove(Employee);
                ctx.SaveChanges();
                DisplayTrackedContextEntities(ctx);
                Console.WriteLine(RemoveHandler, Employee);
            }
        }

        private void btUpdate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            using (NorthwindEntities ctx = new NorthwindEntities())
            {
                var emp = (from Emp in ctx.Employees where e.EmployeeID == 15 select e).First();
                emp.ID = "New ID";
                emp.LastName = "New LastName";
                emp.FirstName = "New FirstName";
                emp.BirthDate = "New BirthDate";
                ctx.SaveChanges();
                DisplayTrackedContextEntities(ctx);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }

        private void DisplayTrackedContextEntities(NorthwindEntities ctx)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private void btAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            using (var ctx = new QueryNorthwindDB1.NorthwindEntities())
            {
                Employee Employees = new Employee
                {
                    ID = "New ID",
                    FirstName = "New FirstName",
                    LastName = "New ",
                    BirthDate = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-28),
                };

                ctx.Employees.Add(Employees);
                ctx.SaveChanges();
                DisplayTrackedContextEntities(ctx);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the errors are these:

> Error CS1936  Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'object'.  'Where' not found.
>
> Error CS1061  'object' does not contain a definition for 'Remove' and no accessible extension method 'Remove' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Try adding *using System.Linq;* at the top of the page.

Comment: Apparently the `Employees` property of `NorthwindEntities` is declared to be `object`, not some set or enumerable.

Comment: It would help if you posted an entire working class including all using statements.

Comment: Hi, I guess those * in your sample are copy paste/formatting errors? Maybe try to tackle down the exact problem and part in your code. I guess it is there: var Employee = (from Employees in ctx.Employees where e.EmployeeID == 15 select e).First(); I guess it should be: var Employee = (from e in ctx.Employees where e.EmployeeID == 15 select e).First<Employee>()

Comment: @Mono - "The errors are marked in italic." - they were trying to use Markdown formatting in their code, which doesn't work.

Comment: Hi everyone, thank you for your reply. Someone asked me to include the whole work so I will I'll do it right now.

Comment: Bernard Vander Beken thank you for your comment. I have attached the whole work so you can see where the errors are coming from if you can help. Thank you.